# I am aspecting to build a calculator with node js the problem is that i can't understand why the console is showing the first value only

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
class Calculator{

Input(add,sub,mul)
{
    this.addition=add;
    
    this.subtract=sub;
    
    this.multiply=mul;
}

reply() 
{
return this.addition 
}


}

Sum=new Calculator();

Sum.Input(4,2);

add=Sum.reply();

console.log(add);
```

*This is the code that is showing the first value only after consoling i get only 4 wheter i am aspecting 6 is sum *

Comment: Your code does not even contain a `+` operator. Why would you expect it to sum anything?

Comment: @Bergi how to do it i don't know about it i am a beginnier

Comment: `Sum.Input(4+2);` would make your code "work", but it's not any different from `Sum.Input(6);` - it's not actually the `Calculator` that calculates something.

Comment: @Bergi So what should i do now sir

Comment: Learn more OOP and redesign the `Calculator`?